# matrix of variable size in global variables , python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I was doing a project in python and I would like to create a global variable which must be a two-dimensional array, but the dimension must be assigned when the user enters it.
how can i declare it initially? and then resize it when I want?
thanks for your attention

Comment: I tried declaring it as a one dimensional array:
button_text = []

and then when I need it I use button_text = np.reshape (button_text, [N, N])

but it does not work

Comment: Please clarify what you want! A [mcve] seems helpful here. Note that the builtin ``[]`` type is a list, not an array; "array" usually refers to ``numpy.array`` or rarely  ``array.array``. Lists are unsized, but neither lists nor arrays need to be pre-declared in the first place.

Comment: Do you really mean an array (as in `array.array`) or do you mean a Python `list`? Using`array.array`is fairly advanced. Assuming you mean a list, in Python you do not *declare* variables, you create them. To make the name global, do `mylist = None` at the top of your program. In each function that refers to it, do `global mylist`, including the function where you assign it a value in response to input. You don't have to *resize* it, you add elements on the end using `append()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare two-dimensional array doing simply this:

```py
a = [[]]
```

If you print it out, you're gonna get something like this: `[[]]` which is two-dimensional array. Then you can append to this array and get elements using `a[y][x]`